# Listen to BlackBerry keyboard events while running in background

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How do I create a background application which continuously listens to key combination, e.g. 1234# or 5678#, to launch another application in BlackBerry.

Comment: You can't create a KeyLogger in BB. You could do that inside your own application though.